# Error when declaring array in Modelica record that is used in association with an external C function call

Tags: arrays, external, record, modelica, openmodelica

plenty of years I was always getting ideal solutions when getting stuck in coding by just going through answers in other posts. Now the time is right for my first own question in this great forum.

I need to have Modelica code (which is later on translated to a FMU - but thats not the topic for now) that reads a MAT-file containing an array (about 10000x3 real values, a 3D-Lookup-Table) that will be handed over to an external C function that returns a scalar value which will then be used in further Modelica code. I don't want to import the data within the C function for performance reasons, as this would lead to the import at every function call instead of one import at initialization (at least this is my goal, if this doesn't work that way please correct me).

Everything is fine on a 64-bit Windows machine using Dymola, but for some technical reasons I need to switch over to OpenModelica on Linux (using a VM), which I'm both not so familiar with.

In detail, I can't find the reason for the following error: If I declare an array as (final) parameter within a record and call that record in the function that contains the external C function call, the translation crashes, even if the variable in the record is not used at all. If I either dismiss the call to the external function or the array, the translation is successful.

Here a small MWE:

```
model MWE

  function callExt
    protected
    internalRecord rec;
    public
//(1)    parameter Real tab[2] = {3,4};
    input Real xi;
    output Real yi;
    external yi=ExternalFunc1_ext(xi) annotation(Include="#include \"ExternalFunc1.c\"");
//(2)  algorithm
//(2)  yi:= xi + 2*xi*xi;
  end callExt;
  
  record internalRecord
    final parameter Real zi = 4;
//(3) final parameter Real tab[2] = {3,4};
  end internalRecord;

  Real y;

algorithm
  y:= callExt(3);

end MWE;
```

Uncommenting (1) works fine. Uncommenting (2) and (3) with deletion of the external call works fine, too. But only uncommenting (3) throws the Error:

*[1] 13:17:44 Translation Error
[/var/lib/jenkins3/ws/LINUX_BUILDS/tmp.build/openmodelica-1.14.2/OMCompiler/Compiler/SimCode/SimCodeUtil.mo: 770:5-770:83]: Internal Error Creation of Modelica functions failed.*

Could there be anything wrong with my configuration on the Linux VM? Or what else could be the reason for the behaviour? The chosen C compiler is gcc. I would be deeply grateful for any hint!

Thank you,
Conrad

EDIT: The error remains the same on a Windows machine:
*[C:/OM114/OM64bit/OMCompiler/Compiler/SimCode/SimCodeUtil.mo: 770:5-770:83]: Internal error Creation of Modelica functions failed.*